# How to optimize any webpage in Chrome to make it more reader friendly?

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, google-chrome-extensions

I am a student and it's been probably more than a month since we've been locked  in our homes. I left most of my books at the hostel, but classes are being taken online. So, simply not studying has never been the option for us, and in order to submit the assignments in time, we need a source of information. That trustworthy source of ours has now become ***"the internet"***.

I am studying Science, and as I search for topics on Google, most of the sites at the top of the search results are university websites. Although they are a great source of genuine information, improper fonts make it hard to read properly. Moreover, most of those webpages were created before `Bootstrap` came into existence, so naturally they are not that reader-friendly. I always have to pinch and zoom into the page in order to read it properly. See this for example:

[image]
**(small fonts are not as comfortable to read compared to something posted on Super User or other Stack Exchange websites)**

So I want to know if there is another way in which I can make the webpage more reader-friendly? See this comparison:
[image] 
*(the difference in readability is clearly visible in this image. See those nice big fonts in the case of Super User and compare them with the snip I took from the other webpage)*

The difference is clear, right?

Basically, if I could change the fonts of the webpage into 
something like I see in famous question answer forums like Stack Exchange or Quora etc. I will be good to go. I think I may get the desired effect by changing the font style using developer tools, but I am looking for some sort of ***extensions or being able to tweak*** with the settings of Chrome. Is this achievable?

Comment: That image is perfectly readable for me.

Comment: yeah, it is readable, but not as comfortable as reading something on superuser.com. It probably has to do something with font. I find it comfortable to read something posted on superuser, but the page that I have given, isn't as comfortable to read. So, I am looking for some extension for chrome, which will let me change the font size and type.

Comment: So your website does not look good enough when zoomed? I found a number of font changing extensions like [Font Swap](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/font-swap-for-google-font/onhgmcpflfncjkdbclmhnfondmindgbg), [Fonts Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fonts-changer/phkenomnahhgjnmpignadbeandfanbil) and [Google Font Previewer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-font-previewer-for/engndlnldodigdjamndkplafgmkkencc) - please share your experience with them.

Comment: Thanks, I need to give them a try.

Comment: That works, thank you.